# How do you make an error in flash somehow display once it's a .swf?

Tags: flash, error-handling

The error I have is

```
Error opening URL "http://www.website.com/something.php?query=someinvalidquery"
```

The query isn't actually supposed to go through, but I'd like some sort of error message saying so.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a `URLLoader` or something, you want to attach an event to it to catch the error. Then you can display a text field or whatever you want.

```
var url = "http://www.website.com/something.php?query=someinvalidquery";
var loader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
loader.load(url);

function errorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace('do whatever to handle the error here.');
}
```

You can also track the httpstatus etc, in case you want to handle redirects and whatnot. The event used are [in the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html?allClasses=1#top)